# How to configure the starting URL used by Capacitor when the native application opens?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, next.js, capacitor

When an application built with Capacitor and, for example, Next.js, starts, it opens a WebView at the homepage path of the website ("/").

How can I configure Capacitor to start the website at a different path, for example, "/login" or "/native"?

I understand that it's possible to use `Capacitor.isNativePlatform()` to conditionally render
components on the home page. However, I'm using SSR, and `isNativePlatform()` must execute on the client-side, and I'd like to preserve the SSR homepage for SEO and loading speed purposes.

It's also possible to detect, on the clientside, when a native platform is used and trigger a redirect. However, this increases loading times and will also show the initial homepage ("/") prior to redirect completing.